# What is the meaning of "given at least"?

Tags: meaning, mathematics

what is the meaning of following similar sentences ?

1. what is the probability of two girls given at least one girl
2. Suppose a family has 2 children, one of which is a boy. What is the probability that both children are boys?

**My understanding of sentence one :** There are two people. One of them is a girl. Find the probability of the next person being a girl.

But it is incorrect !.

Comment: The first sentence appears to be incomplete. What was the correct answer?

Comment: The first sentence comes from this [video](https://youtu.be/XQoLVl31ZfQ) (last minutes). I think you know probability. My answer to the question is 1/2. Because the remaining one can only be a girl or a boy. But the correct answer is 1/3

Comment: I can't understand the english there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are going wrong is this statement:

> There are two people. One of them is a girl. Find the probability of the **next** person being a girl.

You are assuming that the first person is a girl: **Girl**-Girl, **Girl**-Boy. Only one of the two cases have two girls: 1/2.

In actual fact, **either** person could be a girl: **Girl**-Girl, **Girl**-Boy, **Boy**-Girl. Only one of the **three** cases have two girls: 1/3.

The way you want to interpret the statement is:

> There are two people. One of them is a girl. Find the probability of the **other** person being a girl.

So you were nearly right!

---

There are a number of assumptions in the questions:

- In question 1, the choices for each person is assumed to be only boy or girl. If it was boy, girl, man, woman, etc., the answer would be different
- In question 2, is it "**at least** one is a boy" or "**only** one is a boy"?
- Globally, the number of male children to female children is about 51.9:48.1. Are you supposed to take that into account?
- The rate of male to female varies by country
- Some children are born intersex (can't say definitively if they're male or female), estimates range between 0.1% and 1.7%

Source: [Human sex ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_sex_ratio) on Wikipedia

Comment: Thanl you very much for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is more about conditional probability than English. You've correctly worked out that "given at least one girl" means that you should assume that you have one girl.

Thinking about the probably, there are four options in the scenario:
Boy-Boy
Girl-Boy
Boy-Girl
Girl-Girl

Since it says there is at least one girl that excludes boy-boy. This leaves 3 options with 1 of those being girl-girl. Hence, 1/3

Comment: Yeah, It's all about probability. My bad, Thank you very much.